# Display error message only in minibuffer in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I turned on the debug on error in Emacs, which makes the **backtrace** buffer pops to front when ever i have a mis-operation. This is annoying, i just wonder if there is a way to display debug error messages in the minibuffer? if I really want to take a look at the error details, I can then switch to **backtrace** buffer myself.

Comment: Note that if you are writing an Emacs package yourself and want to issue a plain error without starting the debugger, you can use `user-error`. Also, if you want to single-out errors of existing packages you can add error symbols or regexp:s matching error messages to `debug-ignores-errors`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that you're missing a critical aspect. `debug-on-error` doesn't just generate the text of a stack trace as some kind of log<sup>1</sup>; it drops you into an *interactive debugger*, and that more or less necessitates some user-interaction.

I say "more or less" because Emacs doesn't grind to a halt in that situation -- you can continue to do things while the debugger is open -- however you will also notice that `debug-on-error` is ignored while the debugger is open, so if you *don't* interact with the open debugger, subsequent errors will not generate new debug sessions.

It should go without saying that you don't want this option enabled by default. `debug-on-error` is something you enable when you need it, but keep disabled otherwise.

I suspect the real question here is: What are you trying to debug? Because if you're finding this option annoying, it might not be the best option to be using. Or you may be able to use it in a more targeted fashion.

Firstly (sticking with the `debug-on-error` variable) you can limit it to a specific list of error conditions, and/or you can configure `debug-ignored-errors` to exclude errors which you do not wish to debug.

Secondly there are numerous other ways to use the standard debugger, which may well be better solutions. e.g.:

```
;; M-x debug-on-entry FUNCTION
;; M-x cancel-debug-on-entry &optional FUNCTION
;; M-x toggle-debug-on-quit
;; setq debug-on-signal
;; setq debug-on-next-call
;; setq debug-on-event
;; setq debug-on-message REGEXP
;; (debug &rest DEBUGGER-ARGS)
```

(and there's also `edebug`.)

You should, of course, check the manual as well:
<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Debugging` <kbd>RET</kbd>

<sup>1</sup> If you would like an option where it *does* simply log the stack trace to a buffer and then continue, you could raise that as a feature request via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to turn off `debug-on-error`!  Then turn it on again when you get an error message for which you want to see the backtrace -- and provoke the error again.

Of course, this will be useful only for errors that you know how to reproduce.

(P.S. You mean echo area, not minibuffer.)